# What is the proper way to import js, css, scss files to webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, webpack

I'm new to webpack and I am trying to use material-dashboard (https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard) in my project.

Actually, I installed using npm install (https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-dashboard)

So I got this structure in my ./node_modules/material-dashboard:

```
material-dashboard/
├── assets/
|   ├── css/
|   |   ├── bootstrap.min.css
|   |   ├── material-dashboard.css
|   |   └── demo.css
|   ├── js/
|   |   ├── bootstrap-notify.js
|   |   ├── bootstrap.min.js
|   |   ├── chartist.min.js
|   |   ├── demo.js
|   |   ├── jquery-3.1.0.min.js
|   |   ├── material-dashboard.js
|   |   └── material.min.js
|   ├── sass/
|   |    ├── md
|   |    └── material-dashboard.scss
|   └── img/
|
├── documentation/
├── examples/
```

In their example to import they just use link tags like:

`<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../assets/css/material-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/demo-documentation.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

But I'm using webpack so I've tried to import using require in my entry file (app.ts)

```
require('material-dashboard/assets/css/material-dashboard.css');
```

after adding in my webpack.config

```
loader: isTest ? 'null' : "style-loader!css-loader"
```

Apparently it works, I'm not quite sure. But there are 3 css files, 7 js files and 2 .scss files.
I don't want to to import file by file, of course there is a better way.

I would like to know what is the proper way to import in webpack js/css/scss files to use in a project?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried modifying your angular-cli.json file?  Add the respective files under the scripts and styles object.  For example: `"scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]`   Beware, some versions of Angular struggle with assets not in node_modules for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

very easy man

1. for `js` file use

   `import 'the_name_of_npm_package';`
2. for 'css' file use

   `require('the_name_of_npm_package/../../../the_file.css')`;

**NOTE** : if you still find problems u can use `Vue webpack template` with vue cli there are alot of tuts on utube that template is easy for begginers in webpack it has every loader and config you need .

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of files. Do I really need to do a "require" for all files? I cant add an index.js to material-dashboard folder and loop through all files to import all and then just make an require('material-dashboard') in my app.ts file?

Comment: no man you simply can't you have to require and import all one by one,  you can't collect them in one file then require that file cos this is ts or even js u have to bring dependencies one by one .